# Обновление данных в режиме реального времени.

Tags: node.js, php, javascript

Всем привет. Озадачился сделать сайт более динамическим. Обновлять информацию в режиме реального времени. Но все же для начала следует понять принцип работы и выбрать нужное направление.
Что я нашел для такого решения:

1. Node.js - Показалось сложным (Есть
       ли понятная инструкция к данному
       серверу?)
2. XMPP - В принципе не знаю, к вебу
       относится ли он? Это же Jabber
       сервер.
3. Comet - Более легкий способ решения,
       но структура и синтаксис написания
       не понятен.

Какие способы можете посоветовать в решение идеи? С чего начать, ибо в интернете мало **понятной** информации по таким технологиям.

Спасибо.

Comment: Node.js в связке с socket.io - сложно? :DDD

Примеров мало?.. Да там главную открываешь и все понятно

Чисто на будущее - Node.js это, как-бы, платформа а не сервер. Сервер это, например - apache, nginx. Не пишите таких глупостей

С таким же успехом сервером можно называть, например, php, C#, java и т.д.

Comment: А вообще почитайте [тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/47673/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Ну а дальше гугл в помосчь!1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы динамически брать информацию с сервера и подставлять её, нужен AJAX. В переводе это "асинхронный javascript" . В следствие этого, если JS будет отключен, то ajax не сработает.

Comment: AJAX - это нужно лишь в некоторых случаях. Вы меня не поняли, ajax в моем случае это смерть сайту. Мне необходимо проверять, если появились новые данные сайте, то показать их. А если Ajax'ом проверять каждые 10 сек, то серв рухнет, поэтому нужны высокие технологии.

Comment: @Nick 10 лет назад вас бы за фразу "нужен не ajax, а высокие технологии" распяли по меньшей мере))

Comment: Нет нет, не правильно это. Должен быть постоянный запрос на сервер, таймаут 20 мин. В случае появления новой информации сервер должен отдавать её в ответе этого запроса, и сразу должен идти другой запрос на получение следующей информации. Как сделать - не знаю, но очень интересно.

Comment: @Sh4dow, OK =)
@uWeb, Как я знаю node.js и Comet работает так: Первым обращение к серверу, клиент устанавливает соединение с сервером. И как только появляются новые данные, сервер сам отправляет данные клиенту, это куда более экономично, чем клиент будет каждые 1-5 минут спрашивать у сервера о новых данных. Конечно Comet противоречит принципу http, но зато экономия значительная.

Comment: @Nick а я о чем говорю?

Comment: @uWeb, о том де. =) Так у кого какие мысли по этому поводу? =)